# How to access the embedded xml in App_Data folder in C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a xml in App_Data folder which I need to access in a page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Correct way is: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")

Comment: You moderators who closed this as "not a real question" need to be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to get the path to your file

```
Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/yourxmlfile.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Server.MapPath as @Ruben-J pointed out, or you could use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) with [PhysicalApplicationPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx) property of HttpRequest.

```
string appdata = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, @"App_Data\yourxmlfile.xml");
```